# Is it bad to "conceal" a singleton structure in a static class so that it's easier to write?

Tags: c#, static, singleton

Take this example (not something I really use):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// <summary>
/// secrete singleton structure
/// </summary>
public sealed class NameChecker
{
    private static NameChecker _instance;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    public static NameChecker Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock( padlock )
            {
                if( _instance == null )
                {
                    _instance = new NameChecker();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }

    private List<string> names = new List<string>();

    public static bool IsUnique( string key )
    {
        return NameChecker.Instance.names.Contains( key );
    }

    public static void AddName( string key )
    {
        NameChecker.Instance.names.Add( key );
    }

    public static void RemoveName( string key )
    {
        NameChecker.Instance.names.Remove( key );
    }

}
```

using this I can write NameChecker.IsUnique("Sally") instead of writing NameChecker.Instance.IsUnique("Sally).  I include a note with NameChecker so at least on Visual Studio you'll know it's got a singleton implementation.

To me, it seems like the best way to build a singleton class.
Is there any kind of problem this would run into?

Comment: It would seem that you're trying to make the initialization thread safe, but the rest of the methods are not. That may definitely be unintended and non obvious for a singleton.

Comment: Does removing the word “instance” really make it that much easier? Or a I misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for one thing it makes unit testing hard.

Comment: I don’t see where the difficulty would be in unit testing this tbh?

Comment: How do you mock a static class?

Comment: Why would I need to mock it in this situation? Not everything in a unit test needs to be mocked, otherwise nobody would ever use a static class

Comment: OPs question was not specific to this trivial example.

Comment: That’s fair, but then I’d still disagree that testability is an argument in this case especially as we don’t know the full implementation details.